# Probability exactly only 3/5 couples are paired in row

Tags: combinatorics

Lets say there are 5 couples total in a single row which has 10 chairs .What is the probability exactly 3 couples are paired up. The remaining 2 couples must not be paired up- the couples are denoted by (Aa,Bb,Cc,Dd,Ee). One acceptable arrangement would be Aa,D,Bb,Cc,E,d,e)-ie couples Dd and Ee
are not paired up.
I know how to calculate the probability that no couples are paired up using inclusion-exclusion but  have been unsuccessful applying it to this case.

Comment: @RossMillikan: The question fortunately avoids the heteronormative assumptions often made in such questions about couples. Please don't reintroduce them in your comments :-)

Comment: If you have married couples, each comprised of one man and one woman., and you are randomly rearranging them into pairs of one man and woman each, for example as dance partners on a dance floor... there are $5!$ ways in which this can be done.  Now, the number of ways where three couples were partnered with their spouse and the remaining two aren't, just choose which three couples were correctly partnered.  The remaining four people have only one way they can be partnered incorrectly, giving $\binom{5}{3}$ ways this can be done and a probability of $\frac{\binom{5}{3}}{5!}$

Comment: @JMoravitz: Please see my comment above in response to Ross' comment.

Comment: @joriki it is a fair assumption as to the process intended to be discussed.  If you dislike it so much, then write your own textbook that avoids the issue.  If we were to remove the gender assumptions but the intention of the question remains the same, then there is now an ambiguity as to in what ways the couples can be rearranged and repaired up.  The probability will change based on the interpretation.

Comment: @JMoravitz: That's not true. Couples being paired or sitting next to each other in no way depends on their gender. A homosexual or transgender couple can just as easily be paired up or sit next to each other (or not) as a heterosexual one. There are other questions that rely on one of two binary genders being distinguished that are more difficult to state without heteronormative assumptions (and I've answered such questions), but here introducing gender is entirely spurious. By the way, it's not just me who minds this, but many people who appear non-existent in these assumptions.

Comment: If you so insist on changing the flavor so that it is gender neutral, then the interpretation I was going with in my first comment can be described as ten baseball players, comprised of players from five teams, one pitcher and one catcher from each team, are at an allstars practice.  They are paired off as one pitcher and one catcher to practice pitches.  In how many ways can this be done such that exactly three of the pairings are made of teammates?  This gives the $\binom{5}{3}/5!$ answer as before

Comment: Compare this to the problem of if all of the players were generic and not assigned a position, and the catching practice they are paired off without regard to position or team.  There are now $9!!$ different ways they can be paired.  Of them $\binom{5}{3}\times 2$ result in three of the pairs being made of teammates and the remaining two not.  The answer of $\frac{\binom{5}{3}\times 2}{9!!}$ is not equal to the earlier.  "Pairing up" here absolutely depends on the interpretation of what is considered a valid way of pairing up.

Comment: Again... if you dislike the literature and how it depicts what is defined as a valid way of pairing off couples, then come up with your own textbook that avoids the issue like [discrete mathematics - with ducks](https://www.amazon.com/Discrete-Mathematics-Ducks-Sarah-Marie-Belcastro/dp/1466504994)... or try rewording a problem into a gender neutral one before answering it... but you should still be aware of what the intended mathematical problem is before complaining about the flavor.  Answer the math, not the flavor.

Comment: @JMoravitz: I think you misunderstood the question. It talks about couples. $10$ generic players without regard to position or team are not couples. Couples can be paired pitchers and catchers, or paired men and women, or paired women, or whatever; the question merely relies on pairs of people having some special relationship with each other. (By the way, it also doesn't state that the couples are married, another traditional normative assumption that you introduced that wasn't in the question.)

Comment: @JMoravitz: This is not about textbooks. I commented because I was glad to see the problem stated in gender-neutral terms and Ross and you unnecessarily introduced gender in the comments. I don't like the fact that many textbooks are heteronormative, but I don't write comments about it (though I did write [a meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29144) about it, the reaction to which made me leave the site for about a year), and I don't refuse to answer questions copied from such textbooks. That's not the case here; you unnecessarily introduced gender, not an old textbook.

Comment: @RossMillikan: It would mean a lot to me if you could reword your comment in a gender-neutral way.

Comment: Paired up means a husband and wife are sitting next to each other-ie husband1 and wife1 etc

Comment: @joriki:  I have removed my comment, but OP has introduced the traditional concept in the most recent comment.

Comment: @user263904:  you still did not define the seating configuration.  Is it one line of ten, two rows of five facing each other, or what?  Please edit it into the question so it does not get lost in the comments.  Also see joriki's comments on avoiding gender based couples.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I can see three different interpretations to the problem.

In an attempt to clarify the different interpretations and why they are different, I shall reword them slightly.

---

### Interpretation 1

Suppose you have five letters and five envelopes, each of which colored, one of each per color.  Supposing you put these envelopes and letters in a pile without regard to which is which.  What is the probability that at exactly three matching color envelope/letter pairs are adjacent?  There will be $10!$ possible arrangements, of which $\binom{5}{3}\cdot 3!\cdot 2^3 \cdot \binom{4}{2}\cdot 2\cdot \binom{6}{2}\cdot 2 + \binom{5}{3}\cdot 3!\cdot 2^3\cdot 4\cdot 2\cdot 5\cdot 2$ have exactly three matching colored pairs of letter/envelope adjacent.

---

### Interpretation 2

Suppose you have five letters and five envelopes, each of which are colored, one of each per color.  Supposing you mix these and put them into piles of two items each without regard to which are letters vs envelopes.  What is the probability that in exactly three of the piles there are matching colors?  There will be $9!!$ possible arrangements (*with order of piles and order within piles not relevant*), of which $\binom{5}{3}\cdot 2$ having exactly three matching color pairs together.

---

### Interpretation 3

Suppose you have five letters and five envelopes, each of which are colored, one of each per color.  Supposing you mix these and randomly put letters inside of envelopes.  What is the probability that in exactly three envelopes, the matching letter of the same color was inserted?  There will be $5!$ possible arrangements (*with order of piles not relevant*), of which $\binom{5}{3}$ having exactly three matching color pairs together.

Note that in this third interpretation, which is the interpretation I would have gone with for the original problem, it absolutely matters which of the pieces of paper were envelopes and which of the pieces of paper were letters.  The removal or willful ignorance of this information completely changes the meaning of the problem.

---

With the edit, you have clarified which of these interpretations was intended, that being the first one.  More information on how I arrived at the numbers I did:

First, select which three of the letter/envelope color pairs were correctly matched up.  There are $\binom{5}{3}$ ways to choose this.  Then, pick the order in which they appear.  Next, for each of those pairs, pick whether it was the letter or the envelope which appeared first.  $2^3$ options.

Now is where it gets tricky...  Among the remaining colors, exactly one color will be listed earliest alphabetically.  Break into cases based on whether one of the same color pairs appear between the two of this color or not.  In the even that they do, pick which two of the four spaces between or to the sides of the colors they occupy and then which of the spaces was occupied by the letter vs the envelope in $\binom{4}{2}\cdot 2$ ways.  Then, pick which two of the six spaces between or to the sides are occupied by the final remaining color and which was occupied by the letter vs the envelope, taking care not to separate the pairs of same color letter-envelopes.  This can be done in $\binom{6}{2}\cdot 2$ ways.

In the other case, pick which one space between or to the sides of the paired colors our color goes and which order they appear in in $4\cdot 2$ ways.  Next, exactly one of the final remaining color must split these apart, and one more space must be selected for the final piece, then pick which was the letter vs the envelope which can be done in $5\cdot 2$ ways.

This gives the probability of $\dfrac{\binom{5}{3}\cdot 3!\cdot 2^3\cdot \binom{4}{2}\cdot 2\cdot \binom{6}{2}\cdot 2 + \binom{5}{3}\cdot 3!\cdot 2^3\cdot 4\cdot 2\cdot 5\cdot 2}{10!}$

Comment: Please see my rephrased statement. There are no piles -just seats in a row

Comment: Please explain how you get 6 choose 2 in the first case. Where are these 6 places to select. Maybe you could show an example with the paired and unpaired order shown . Thank you.

Comment: Represent the same colored pairs as $\langle\rangle$.  So, after having sorted and arranged the same color pairs our current arrangement looks like $~\langle\rangle~\langle\rangle~\langle\rangle~$.  Now, represent the first of the unpaired colors as stars.  Had they been placed in different gaps, it might look something like $~\star~\langle\rangle~\star~\langle\rangle~\langle\rangle~$.  The available positions are the gaps to the left or right of stars and or angles... there are six such positions regardless how the stars were interspersed.

Comment: If I were to display the available gaps as underlines to make it more obvious, $\underline{~}\star\underline{~}\langle\rangle\underline{~}\star\underline{~}\langle\rangle\underline{~}\langle\rangle\underline{~}$.  We choose two of those gaps into which we place the final color.  In the other case where both of the first color were placed into the same gap, we would have looked like $\underline{~}\star\color{red}{\underline{~}}\star\underline{~}\langle\rangle\underline{~}\langle\rangle\underline{~}\langle\rangle\underline{~}$ and the gap marked red *must* be used.

Comment: Your stars and dashes are very good. I need to think about the positioning and get back to you

Comment: Mr Moravitz -Thank you for solution . I understand your approach pretty well. I wonder if there is a general technique such as inclusion-exclusion that can be applied

Comment: The sarcasm is quite uncalled for.

Comment: @JMoravitz  I deleted the question posted today on jan 29 since it is a duplicate. My head is rattled. Sorry again.